# How to reuse code sequentially, immediately after definition?

Tags: java

I want to perform many simple operations in succession.
In java, I occasionally use methods as procedures, like this:

```
doA(x);
doB(x, 1);
doB(x, 2);
doC(x);
```

It does everything I want but it's hard to look at and the sequence of events is not as clear as possible. I often do this instead:

```
(A part I)
(A part II)
(B part I)
(B part II)
(B part III)
(C part I)
(C part II)
(C part III)
(C part IV)
```

This is wonderful for understanding the code because you can see exactly the sequence of evens the computer performs, if the operations are simple (for example, string manipulation with a little bit of flow control).
The problem comes when I want to do B and then something similar to B but just a bit different. I want to reuse the code in case I need to do changes to both instances of B. In other languages, I often leave that code in the middle but put it into a small lambda and execute it twice with different parameters. It may look something like this:

```
(A part I)
(A part II)
define makeB:
    (B part I)
    (B part II)
    (B part III)
x = makeB(true);
y = makeB(false);
(C part I)
(C part II)
(C part III)
(C part IV)
```

This is readable top-to-bottom and it is clear how B is just a part of this one process and doesn't belong anywhere else.
Are java lambdas applicable for this? The grand goal behind lambdas in java seems to be something completely different from my goal. If they are applicable, how do I use them for simple code, like string manipulation? If they are not, are there any other tools that remedy the problem I expressed in the very first approach?

Comment: *"The grand goal behind lambdas in java seems to be something completely different from my goal"* - What leads you to this conclusion?

Comment: Abstraction, make some sort of facade?

Comment: What exactly is hard to look at and not clear to understand the sequence of events of in that first example? Are you saying you want to show what is happening inside of `doB` and don't like that the method "hides" its contents?

Comment: Maybe we just need a more concrete example.

Comment: If `doA(x);
doB(x, 1);
doB(x, 2);
doC(x);` is hard to look at, maybe then you should use better names for the procedures.

Comment: Thanks to kaya3, I have pushed forward myself, browsed through more documentation instead of tutorials, and found a solution. I have included a more concrete example as well.

Comment: Forgot to answer Thilo's question - yes, I don't like that the method "hides" its contents. Especially since any text editor for coding can hide contents on demand. In other contexts, I am happy that methods hide their content (when sorting a list, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading about lambdas online, especially in tutorials (both official by Oracle and unofficial) gave me a wrong impression, since most were about making a new functional interface for a specialized task. Thanks to user kaya3 for questioning my conclusion.

I've found out that you can use `Function<T,R>` from `java.util.function` for use cases like mine and it doesn't require any further setup.

```
Function<Boolean, String> makeB = (Boolean bee) -> {...}
x = makeB.apply(true);
y = makeB.apply(false);
```

The comments asked for actual code and I owe it. Not final but here's how I have currently employed a lambda. It is not for String operations but it's the one example I have at hand. I do plan to actually use it for String operations later.

```
rootElement.addChildElement(StructureElement.newStructureElement("HiddenTag", false, false, 10f, null, null, MultiplicityEnum.ZERO_OR_MORE,
    Arrays.asList(areaOfUsageHiddenTag, stylisticHiddenTagPattern, otherHiddenTagPattern),
    null, trimCommaTransformers, (List) null)
    .addPrefixElement(nonMandatorySpace)
);

Function<Boolean, StructureElement> newMeaningBlock = (Boolean numberRequired) -> StructureElement.newStructureElementNoParse("MeaningBlock", MultiplicityEnum.ZERO_OR_MORE)
    .addChildElement(StructureElement.newStructureElement("MeaningNumber", true, false, 12f, null, null, numberRequired ? MultiplicityEnum.ONE : MultiplicityEnum.ZERO_OR_ONE, meaningNumberPattern, null, trimCommaTransformers).addPrefixElement(nonMandatorySpace))
    .addChildElement(meaningBlock2)

    .addChildElement(StructureElement.newStructureElementNoParse("AdditionalMeaningBlock", MultiplicityEnum.ZERO_OR_MORE)
            .addChildElement(StructureElement.newStructureElement("MeaningShade", false, false, 12f, null, null, MultiplicityEnum.ONE_OF_MANY, meaningShadePattern, null, trimCommaTransformers)
                    .addPrefixElement(nonMandatorySpace)
                    .addChildElement(shadeMeaningBlock)
            )
            .addChildElement(StructureElement.newStructureElement("BevGender", true, false, 12f, null, null, MultiplicityEnum.ONE_OF_MANY, headerPattern, null, trimCommaTransformers)
                    .addPrefixElement(nonMandatorySpace)
                    .addChildElement(StructureElement.newStructureElement("BevGenderTag", false, false, 10f, null, null, MultiplicityEnum.ONE, bevGenderTagPattern, null, trimCommaTransformers)
                            .addPrefixElement(nonMandatorySpace))
                    .addChildElement(nonMandatorySpace)
                    .addChildElement(StructureElement.newStructureElementNoParse("MeaningIllustrationBlock", MultiplicityEnum.ZERO_OR_MORE)
                            .addChildElement(StructureElement.newStructureElement("MeaningIllustration", false, true, 12f, null, null, MultiplicityEnum.ONE_OF_MANY, meaningIllustrationPattern, null, trimCommaTransformers)
                                    .addPrefixElement(nonMandatorySpace)
                                    .addChildElement(StructureElement.newStructureElement("MeaningIllustrationDef", false, false, 12f, null, null, MultiplicityEnum.ZERO_OR_ONE, meaningIllustrationDefPattern, null, null))
                            )
                            .addChildElement(StructureElement.newStructureElement("Tag", false, false, 10f, null, null, MultiplicityEnum.ONE_OF_MANY,
                                    Arrays.asList(areaOfUsageTag, stylisticTagPattern, otherTagPattern),
                                    null, trimCommaTransformers, (List) null)
                                    .addPrefixElement(nonMandatorySpace)
                                    .addChildElement(nonMandatoryDot)
                            )
                    )
            )
    );

rootElement.addChildElement(newMeaningBlock.apply(false));
rootElement.addChildElement(newMeaningBlock.apply(true));
```

There are a lot more `rootElement.addChildElement(...)` statements before and after this, all are just as important, especially when referring to it during debugging. I have left out all but a few of the statements to outline the important part.
I could have alternatively used XML or JSON to encode this structure and read it in java but I have opted for this instead and it successfully avoids problems related to just XML or JSON. And this will work in the future for actual code that isn't just creating structures.

Comment: `BiFunction<T,U,R>` was also essential in what I am making.